# The font has chinese characters but I can't type it out?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding

I am using a font, Kievit for a design project.
It is an English font however it says it supports Chinese characters.
By using Character Maps, I can see there is Chinese characters in it.

But every time I type out a Chinese character in Photoshop or words, the font family will change to something else. I can't change it to Kievit. I suspect the Chinese characters are mapped incorrectly to the unicode or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [character repertoire of the Kievit font](https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/kievit/regular#tab-glyphs) consists of Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic letters and a set of special characters. So whichever Character Map you are using, it apparently shows things wrong; it might be using some kind of a multi-font display.

Comment: I am using Windows Character Map, it has Chinese characters in it but it has a lot of "Toufu" [] characters as well. So I think you are right, Chinese is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie in whether this font is actually using simplified chinese or traditional chinese.  I have some fonts that do the same thing with me.  A quick way to test this theory out would be to go to Google Translate type in "book".  Translate it to traditional chinese, copy the character, and go into photoshop, set the font to Kievit and Paste.  If that doesn't work try the same thing but translate it to Simplified Chinese.

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: I also had this problem......  some programs, including Word, check the font's embedded recommendation for simplified or traditional and switch the font if it doesn't match your keyboard  (even if the font actually has both).